# enum in a class in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

How do you access a classes enum from outside of the class?

```
  class Element
  {
    enum Type
    {
        case AUDIO
        case LIGHT
        case THERMOSTAT
    }
  }

  var a = Element.Type.LIGHT   // error: 'Element.Type.Type' does not have a member named 'LIGHT'

  var b = Element.LIGHT   // error: 'Element.Type' does not have a member named 'LIGHT'
```

Answer (score 11):

A `Type` property already exists (unlucky name :)), just rename it to something else, such as:

```
class Element
{
    enum EnumType
    {
        case AUDIO
        case LIGHT
        case THERMOSTAT
    }
}

var a = Element.EnumType.LIGHT
```

Comment: ugg! Aren't reserved words supposed to be a different color!?

Comment: It's not a reserver keyword :) If not wrong `Type` is a static property returning the type of a type, similar to what in objective C the `class` selector does, like in `[NSString class]`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to remain the name `Type` but you need backticks (`)

```swift
class Element {
    enum `Type` {
        case AUDIO
        case LIGHT
        case THERMOSTAT
    }
}

let a: Element.`Type` = .LIGHT
```

However the following pattern I have tested seems not working:

```swift
let a = Element.`Type`.LIGHT // Compile error
```